# Design pattern for populating an object with data

Tags: object, design-patterns

Is there a design pattern that covers populating an object with data?

More specifically I am thinking about an object that can contain many different data fields. When I request such an object from a method I would like to be able to specify the amount of data populated, eg. LOW, MID, HIGH but not limited to these values and maybe even more fine grained. It can be done by just creating a ENUM and call the method with that ENUM as a parameter. But is there a desing pattern that describes a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a Builder, could be something like:

```
public class DogBuilder {
    private final Dog dog = new Dog();

    public static DogBuilder primitive() {
        return new DogBuilder()
                .withName("Name")
                .withWeight(12.1);
    }
    
    public DogBuilder withName(String n) {
        dog.setName(n);
        return this;
    }
    public DogBuilder withWeight(double w) {
        dog.setWeight(w);
        return this;
    }
    
    public DogBuilder withOwner(Human h) {
        dog.setOwner(h);
        return this;
    }
    public DogBuilder withHome(Address a) {
        dog.setAddress(a);
        return this;
    }
    
    public Dog build() {
        return dog;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Dog d = DogBuilder.primitive().withOwner(new Owner()).build();
```

Whether the Builder should have the resulting objects as a field is arguable. Probably in most cases you'd want to keep all its fields and then combine them into the resulting object. Especially if you want to keep classes immutable.

Answer (score 0):

> It can be done by just creating a ENUM and call the method with that ENUM as a parameter.

I guess you're looking for a Factory, potentially combined with a Builder, as @stanislav-bashkyrtsev suggested.

Something like this:

```
public class StuffFactory{
    public IStuff Create(StuffTypes type){
        switch(type){
            ....
        }
    }
}

public enum StuffTypes{
   Simple,
   Complex,
   EvenMoreComplex
}
```

All you have to do here is populate the *case* statements, potentially leveraging a Builder to populate the fields you need.

Moreover, since the Factory is returning an Interface, you can use different Builders based on the final implementation type that will be returned.